# Android Share Button Zoomed

Tags: android, zooming, share-button

[image]

I have a clasic share button on android with material design. 
I test it on Samsung S2  and it's ok, but on S4 it's zoomed like that.

I searched on net, but I didn't manage to find something.

Any idea ?

Comment: what Image ? this is an android share button, but it's zoomed, and  I don't get it why ?!

On S2, it looks good, but on S4 it's like this

Comment: Nobody knows the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my manifest and it solved my problem.

```html
    <supports-screens 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```